# spoj julka big number implementation

Tags: c++

This is  my solution to **JULKA problem in Spoj.**
http://www.spoj.com/problems/JULKA/.

The problem is simple.Given two numbers sum and diff ,we have to find 2 nos a and b such that **a+b=sum,a-b=diff

sum,diff lie in between (1,10^100)**

It's implementation in python is trivial.I'm trying to **implement in C++ using arrays.**   After several hours of debugging,I'm getting the correct ans for every test case that I checked.

SAMPLE INPUT (no of testcases fixed=10)
5 1
4 2
4 0
100 10
(6 more test cases)

SAMPLE OUTPUT
3 
2
3
1
2
2
55
45

**Valid cases include only those which give perfect integer solution.**
For example cases like (10,3),(100,15),(10,10),(20,20),(40,50),(7,11) are not valid and they won't be given.

However Spoj server still says wrong answer....Can you **please help me out in finding out for which test case it's failing?**

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int t=10,carry,a[105],b[105],temp[105];
char sum[105],diff[105];

while(t--)
{
    cin>>sum;          // sum and diff accepted as strings
    cin>>diff;
    int i,j,k=0,r;
    for(i=strlen(sum)-1,j=strlen(diff)-1;i>=0,j>=0;i--,j--)  
    {
        if( sum[i] >= diff[j] )  //loop to find sum -diff.Result in temp
            temp[k++]=sum[i]-diff[j];
        else
        {   temp[k++]=10+sum[i]-diff[j];
            r=i-1;
            while(1)
            {

                if(sum[r]=='0')
                {
                    sum[r]='9';
                    r--;
                    continue;
                }
                sum[r]=(char)(sum[r]-1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(i>=0)        // for digits after diff's msb,we simply pass it to temp 
    {   for(j=i;j>0;j--)
        {
            temp[k++]=sum[j]-'0';
        }
        if(sum[0]!='0')             //if last digit is 0,we don't want it
            temp[k++]=sum[0]-'0';
    }

    //finding the smaller
    j=0;                     // a=(sum-diff)/2
    carry=0;
    for(i=k-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   a[j++]=(temp[i]+10*carry)/2;
        carry=(temp[i]+10*carry)%2; //a msb at 0
    }
    int cnt_a=k;


    //finding bigger

    k=0,i=j-1,r=strlen(diff)-1;  // b=a+diff
    carry=0;
    while(i>=0&&r>=0)           
    {
        b[k++]= (a[i]+(diff[r]-'0')+carry)%10;  //a lsb at j-1,b lsb at 0
        carry=(a[i--]+(diff[r--]-'0')+carry)/10;
    }

    while(i>=0) // if a>diff for digits after diff's msb,we pass it to b
    {   b[k++]= (a[i]+carry)%10;
        carry=  (a[i--]+carry)/10;
    }

    while(r>=0) // if diff>a for digits after a's msb,we pass it to b
    {   b[k++]= ( (diff[r]-'0')+carry)%10;
        carry=  ( (diff[r--]-'0')+carry)/10;
    }
    int cnt_b=k;

    //printing a and b

    if(cnt_b>1)      //printing b

    {   if(b[cnt_b-1]!=0)          //if msb was 0 we don't print it
            printf("%d",b[cnt_b-1]);


        for(i=cnt_b-2;i>=0;i--)
            printf("%d",b[i]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    else if(cnt_b==1) //if only 1 digit we print msb even if it's 0
        printf("%d\n",b[0]);


    if(cnt_a>1)          //printing b

    {   if(a[0]!=0)
            printf("%d",a[0]);   //if msb was 0 we don't print it

        for(i=1;i<cnt_a;i++)
            printf("%d",a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else if(cnt_a==1)       //if only 1 digit we print msb even if it's 0
        printf("%d\n",a[0]);


}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: @rsd_unleashed `implement in C++ using arrays.`  Which is why vanilla C++ is not a good language to do this assignment in.  Unless you've written a "Big number" class, tested it, etc., it becomes a task in itself to write something like this.  Stick with using Python, or Java's "BigNumber" class, or a third-party C++ library that handles big numbers, or legitimately write your own class.

Answer (score -1):

15 8 means if the sum is odd diff is even or vice

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow, although this is an answer to the question could you provide more detail into this or how you got to this?